# Jooq schema name as query parameter

Tags: schema, jooq

I need to change the schema name of a query based on the user input.
How can I pass/change the schema name to the JOOQ query at runtime ?
Thx.

Answer (score 0):

#### A jOOQ based solution:

There's a feature called [runtime schema mapping](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/code-generation/codegen-advanced/codegen-config-database/codegen-database-catalog-and-schema-mapping/) that you want to look into. You can provide pairs of input/output schema names, which will be used to map schema names of all objects in generated SQL:

```java
DSLContext ctx = DSL.using(connection, new Settings().withRenderMapping(
    new RenderMapping().withSchemata(
        new MappedSchema().withInput("INPUT").withOutput("OUTPUT")
    )
));
```

You can now use the above `DSLContext` to write queries like this:

```java
ctx.select(INPUT.TABLE.COL).from(INPUT.TABLE).fetch();
```

The resulting SQL would be:

```sql
select OUTPUT.TABLE.COL from OUTPUT.TABLE
```

#### A SQL based solution

Instead of fully qualifying the schema, you could also prevent the schema name from being generated using `Settings.withRenderSchema(false)`, and then use [`DSLContext.setSchema()`](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/latest/org.jooq/org/jooq/DSLContext.html#setSchema(org.jooq.Schema)) or some other means to specify the default schema of your database connection.